# Android Alarm Manager is not able to execute a periodic function

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background-service

I am using Android Alarm Manager to execute some background code in flutter. The code runs perfectly when it is scheduled in main.dart file. However, when i do the same in another file, it does not get executed. I am initialising android alarm manager from main.dart but scheduling a function in some other file.
Main.dart code:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
notificationIntitialize();
await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
runApp(const MyApp());
}

other.dart code:

void initState() {

 printX();
}


void printX() {
 print('Print hello clicked');
 final int helloAlarmID = 0;
 AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
     Duration(seconds: 10), helloAlarmID, printHelloX);
}

void printHelloX() {
     final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
 final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
 print("[$now] Hello, world in home! isolate=${isolateId}");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your imports.
Add the alarm manager package import on both files, and add an import of your `second.dart` into `main.dart`.

Also don't forget that each scheduled alarm can only have an Unique ID.